# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList. Other answers did not solve

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, classnotfoundexception, searchview

I want to use [this library to create this SearchView](https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable). The project and the tutorial given on the Github page was for Android Studio, **but I use Eclipse**. So what I did was that I created a library project in Eclipse and copied all the code from the custom-searchable module here.

Then I created a project named custom-searchable-demo and copied all the code from the module named demo there. But I have been getting all the weird **errors** for a day. Right now I am getting:

```
08-16 09:56:13.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.content_provider.CustomSuggestionsProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo.content_provider.CustomSuggestionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.edsilfer.custom_searchable_demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have attached both the Eclipse projects on mediafire i.e. the [**library project**](http://www.mediafire.com/download/g0r548r506arfzx/custom-searchable-demo.zip) and the [**demo project**](http://www.mediafire.com/download/msybh78uonw4jfl/custom-searchable.zip).

***Note:*** I have not posted the code, because the Eclipse projects are attached, and the AS code is here but if you think I should post it, lemme know in a comment, I will post it. Please also mention if I should post both the library project and the demo project, or the demo project only

**Secondly, if you try to download the project and run it, please let me know if it works for you or not in a comment. This will atleast make sure that if there is something wrong with the project or I am doing something wrong. Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse on the menu bar click on the "Project" tab end than click on "Clean..." selection. Click "Clean all projects" selection and than click the OK button.

Sorry for my english

Comment: I have done this (and a bunch of other stuff) tons of times - did not work

Comment: No as I mentioned, I don't use AS, I use Eclipse.

Comment: Go to eclipse directory and open the "eclipse.ini" file. Add at first line "-clean" without apices and save. Open eclipse and try to run the app.

Comment: Though just upvoted your comment, have you tried this yourself? Because I don't want to make things further problematic.

Comment: I have this option in my eclipse configuration and is more efficient.